# flex encrypte local mp3

Tags: apache-flex, encryption, local-storage

i'm building a MP3 service where an online file gets streamed from the internet and save in the local storage ( to prevent future data traffic ). Considdering this, i would like to encrypte the local file or don't make is usable outside my application. I managed to encrypte / decrypte the file but can't load a bytes array into a sound object. Also the decryption of a file takes about 5 seconds wich is too long.

I was thinking of making the MP3 corrupt and then rewrite the file again.
Can somebody help me in this matter?

Thanks

Comment: You could build your own audio format that no other player supports--this is kind of what Apple did w/ iTunes.  In my own personal view, DRM Schemes often hinder customer experience without stopping pirates.  Your resources may be better spent creating a better product [or business model] than DRM.

Comment: Changing the file format is not an easy task and my deadline is comming closer. Any other options?

Comment: My suggestion is to stop worrying about whether your customers use the mp3s in other apps. That probably isn't helpful, though, especially if your 'business backers' are adamant about DRM.

Comment: Ok. Another question, is there a way to accept a drop on a Toggle Button?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. If you have another question; I suggest you write it up as a new post, with as much code as possible.

Comment: one solution would be to store them in the sqllite db, which automatically encrypts the db for you(upon your instructions in the code) This might work for a few MP3s, but it the library gets big, then the sql lite might get slow.(Normally I would be against storing media files into the DB)

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar for a VOD app I built last year. I ran into the same problems as you: client demanded the video be downloadable, but not be viewable anywhere but the app. DRM was out of the question for various reasons, so we decided to go with encryption. Our first schemes were too slow (5-10 seconds on an iPad 3) so we decided to destroy the file instead.

Basically, you need to look at the structure of your file format. For my format, the first 32 bytes were the header. We didn't want to destroy the header, because it is essential to the file and we did not want to risk corrupting it. So instead, we looked at the data *after* the header. We decided to disrupt every 16KB for byte 33 to like 1024KB or something (I won't say the exact range for obvious reasons).

Our disruption pattern was simple and easily reversible (needed if you want to play the file, obviously):

```
byte = MAX_BYTE_VALUE - byte;
```

That will basically flip values. So if `MAX_BYTE_VALUE` is 10 and byte is 3, it becomes 7. If it is 7, it becomes 3. There is no way it can fall out of range and no way the pattern could be broken. So we ran that on a small range of bytes at the beginning of the file, something like 60-100 bytes total, and our video file was still playable, but no sound existed anymore and the image was completely corrupted (large blocks of purple and pink with lots of static) as well.

Obviously, a DRM solution probably would have been better. But the client was adamant about not using DRM and insisted we use an encryption method instead. This method was effective and efficient, resulting in no dropped frames for my app while running. Hopefully that gives you an idea of how you could do this.

Comment: How is this different than a DRM Solution?  [But, +1 regardless]

Comment: @Reboog711 I'm not entirely sure what the difference is (never worked with proper DRM schemes). This method meant the client didn't need to rewrite their site's video player, though, which is what they were trying to avoid.